# Limit files downloaded - IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, download

I have my own web site (created in asp.net) on local IIS. From this web site I download files. I can download only 9 files. Is any option in IIS settings which limit number of downloaded files ? Maybe in metabase.xml ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS enforces a connection limit on non-server OS's.  I assume you are on Windows7/Vista.   I suspect you are running into this limit.  You can [see here](http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm) for a detailed breakdown of the connection limits by OS version.

The good news is that when you deploy to a real server OS, you won't have this problem.

Comment: I try on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7. When site is started from IIS I can download only 9 files, when I started my web site from Visual Studio (with developer IIS) on Windows 7 there is no limit.